# recordMyDesktop on Ubuntu Studio audio "DEFAULT"?

Tags: ubuntu-studio, jack, recordmydesktop

I installed Ubuntu Studio so I could do multi-media including screencasts but I found the audio for recordmydesktop doesn't work "out of the box".  Here is the "Advanced" tab for sound.

[image: recordMyDesktop:Advanced]

Note 2 things:
 1. The Device is "DEFAULT".
 2. jack_lsp returned no ports

If "DEFAULT" isn't right for Ubuntu Studio, does that mean I've messed up my configuration somehow?

If jack_lsp returns no ports, how do I get it to work?  There are a huge number of items under the "Audio" dropdown menu for Ubuntu Studio but I see no "jack" anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't launch Jack.  You should launch it in order to use jack based applications.  There should be a launcher for QJackCTL (Q Jack Control) in your Audio production submenu.

What is Jack?  You can google "jack ubuntu studio" and get many results, as
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation where it states:
"Pulse Audio, the default sound server in Ubuntu, is not designed to work at low latency. You can connect Pulse Audio to Jack, which has been designed for this purpose." (...) 
"Jack is a real-time sound server, aimed for very low latency settings with your sound card. You can use it with the integrated sound card of any computer." (...) "Some applications need Jackd to run, some don't."

Hope this helps!